# Why is Onblur not working (JQuery/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have the following input field for which i want to pull suggestions when a user types:

```
<input type = 'text' name= 'target' id='target' style='width:150px' onblur ='setTimeout('removeSuggestions()', 20);' onkeyup ='getSuggestions(this.value);'/>
```

There is a "suggestions" div below it and I am using the following javascript.

```
function getSuggestions(value){
   if (value !=""){
   $.post("target.php", {targPart:value}, function(data) {
     $("#suggestions").html(data);
    if(value.length>2){
        doCSS();
        }

   });
   } else {
    removeSuggestions();
    }

  }

   function removeSuggestions(){

   $("#suggestions").html("");
   undoCSS();
   }
  function addText(value){

      $("#target").val(value);

  }
  function doCSS(){
  $("#suggestions").css({
      'border' : 'solid',
       'border-width': '1px'
    });

  }

  function undoCSS(){
   $("#suggestions").css({
      'border' : '',
       'border-width': ''
    });
  }
```

I figure that when i click outside the field....the suggestions div should vanish or do i have to do it more explicitly?

Thanks!

Comment: So you are basically reinventing [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
<input type = 'text' name= 'target' id='target' style='width:150px' onblur ='setTimeout('removeSuggestions()', 20);' onkeyup ='getSuggestions(this.value);'/>
```

For some reason you are using single quotes to surround your attribute values, but then you are also using it to surround your function call in setTimout().  So when the browser parses it, it stops the attribute at

```
onblur ='setTimeout('
```

And you get JS errors.

Use double quotes to surround your HTML attributes.

```
<input type = "text" name= "target" id="target" style="width:150px" onblur ="setTimeout('removeSuggestions()', 20);" onkeyup = "getSuggestions(this.value);"/>
```

Also, that's not the best way to use setTimout(). Use an anonymous function instead.

Also, binding event listeners inline is not a best practice. Instead use unobtrusive JavaScript.

```
$(function(){
    $('#target').blur(function(e) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            removeSuggestions()
        }, 20);
    });

    $('#target').keyup(function(e) {
        getSuggestions(e.target.value);
    });
});
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 5):

you have got your single quotes inside other single quotes:

```
onblur ='setTimeout('removeSuggestions()', 20);'
```

should read

```
onblur='setTimeout("removeSuggestions()", 20);'
```

Also, I would recommend not putting spaces between HTML tag attributes and their values (see comment), it might cause issues on some browsers with strict parsers.

Comment: +1 I would clarify that you mean not putting spaces between the attribute name, equals sign and value. The way you have that worded now, it could seem to be you mean there should be no spaces between each of multiple attributes, which of course there must be. `<tag attribute1="value1" [space here] attribute2="value2"/>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type = 'text' name= 'target' id='target' style='width:150px' onblur ="setTimeout('removeSuggestions()', 20);" onkeyup ='getSuggestions(this.value);'/>
```

Since removeSuggestions should be treated as literal , and hence, you should use double quote for the attribute values.